# Calling a PowerShell Script from another PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to call a PowerShell script from another PowerShell script which takes a parameter -Install:

```
PS C:\Users\abc\Downloads\InstallPackage-2022\InstallPackage> .\Install_Package.ps1 -Install
```

What command can I use to call this from my other PowerShell Script?

i tried the following which did not work:

```
Invoke-Expression "C:\InstallPackage-2022\InstallPackage\Install_Package.ps1" -Install

Start-Process "C:\InstallPackage-2022\InstallPackage\Install_Package.ps1" -ArgumentList "-Install" -Verb runAs;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the referenced powershell script, from referencing powershell script(say Referencing_Install_Package.ps1), as given below:

```
& "C:\InstallPackage-2022\InstallPackage\Install_Package.ps1" -Install
```

Now you can call the referencing powershell as given below:

```
PS C:\Users\abc\Downloads\InstallPackage-2022\InstallPackage> 
 .\Referencing_Install_Package.ps1
```